# How to print three different rectangles in picturebox side by side vb.net

Tags: vb.net, graphics

i have three different buttons in a form which have three different widths and heights of a rectangle.each time the button is clicked , the width and height is loaded and eachtime picturebox is clicked rectangle is created on a picturebox.i want the three rectangles to go side by side in X axis but wheneven i click the first rectangle and click on picturebox, three same rectangle is drawn. i want some help with the loop. here is my code.

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    Dim myGraphics As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
    Dim myPen As Pen
    myPen = New Pen(Drawing.Color.Black, 1)
    myGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, pt1.X, pt1.Y, pt2.X, pt2.Y)
    myGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, pt3.X, pt3.Y, pt4.X, pt4.Y)
End Sub


Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click       'MessageBox.Show(e.Clicks)
    Dim myGraphics As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
    midpoint.X = (pt1.X + pt2.X) / 2
    midpoint.Y = (pt3.Y + pt4.Y) / 2
    Dim l(2) As Point
    l(0).X = midpoint.X
    l(0).Y = midpoint.Y
    If e.X >= midpoint.X Then

        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To 2

            If (i > 0) Then
                l(i).X += l(i - 1).X + myRect.Width
                l(i).Y = midpoint.Y - myRect.Height
                Dim myPen As Pen
                myPen = New Pen(Drawing.Color.Black, 1)
                myGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, l(i).X, l(i).Y, myRect.Width, myRect.Height)


            Else
                l(i).X = midpoint.X
                l(i).Y = midpoint.Y - myRect.Height
                Dim myPen As Pen
                myPen = New Pen(Drawing.Color.Black, 1)
                myGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, l(i).X, l(i).Y, myRect.Width, myRect.Height)




            End If



        Next





    End If
```

Comment: First things first, NEVER call `CreateGraphics`. If you want to draw on a `PictureBox`, handle the `Paint` event of that `PictureBox` and use the `Graphics` object provided. If you want to initiate drawing on a `Click` event, calculate the data required to do the drawing, store it in one or more fields and then call `Invalidate` to raise a `Paint` event. Read the data from the field(s) in the `Paint` event handler to do the drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what jmcilhinney is talking about:

[image]

```
Public Class Form1

    ' these represent the x-axis?
    Private pt1 As New Point(0, 100)
    Private pt2 As New Point(200, 100)

    ' these represent the y-axis?
    Private pt3 As New Point(100, 0)
    Private pt4 As New Point(100, 200)

    ' represents the size of the box to draw
    Private myRect As New Size(30, 20)

    Private numClicks As Integer
    Private rects As New List(Of Rectangle)

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
        ' draw the x and y axis
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, pt1, pt2)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, pt3, pt4)

        ' draw all the rectangles in our list
        For Each rc As Rectangle In rects
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, rc)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Dim origin As New Point((pt1.X + pt2.X) / 2, (pt3.Y + pt4.Y) / 2)
        Dim clickedPt As Point = PictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
        If clickedPt.X > origin.X Then
            If numClicks < 3 Then
                Dim rc As New Rectangle(New Point(origin.X + (numClicks * myRect.Width), origin.Y - myRect.Height), myRect)
                rects.Add(rc)
                numClicks = numClicks + 1
                PictureBox1.Invalidate()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```